# Changing classes names after clicking on it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 6 and Bootstrap. I'm trying to change classes names after click(to change its size) using `document.getElementsByClassName`. I've created my elements using `*ngFor`. After clicking on them `coinDetails(coin,i)` function starts working.

Right now, after clicking on element it increases the size(class changes to: `col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize`), and after second click on the same element, it decreases the size(class changes to: `col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize`), as I wanted.

But when I click on one element and then on another (`index` changes), first one is staying increased.

I don't know, how to detect if variable `index` changed.

Maybe a screenshot would explain it better. 
In this situation, I clicked on 'LTC' box at the beggining, and then on 'STRAT' box. 'STRAT' increased the size, but 'LTC' stayed also enlarged, although it's no longer the active one.
I would like this 'LTC' box to be the same size as 'ZEC', or 'BTE' after it stopped being active one.

[image]

```
    coinDetails(coin, index) {
    if (this.detailToggle[index]) {
      this.detailToggle[index] = false;
      this.col = document.getElementsByClassName("resize")[index];
      this.col.className = "col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize";

    } else {

      this.col = document.getElementsByClassName("resize")[index];
      this.col.className = "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize";

      this.detailToggle.fill(false);
      this._data.getCoin(coin).subscribe(res => {
        this.details = res["DISPLAY"][coin]["USD"];
        this.detailToggle[index] = true;
        this._data.getChart(coin).subscribe(res => {
          let coinHistory = res["Data"].map(a => a.close);

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.chart[index] = new Chart("canvas" + index, {
              type: "line",
              data: {
                labels: coinHistory,
                datasets: [
                  {
                    data: coinHistory,
                    borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                    fill: false
                  }
                ]
              },
              options: {
                tooltips: {
                  callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                      return "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString();
                    }
                  }
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                  display: false
                },
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [
                    {
                      display: false
                    }
                  ],
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      display: false
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            });
          }, 250);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid use of DOM manipulation on Angular, instead use ngClass (https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), in your html you should have something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of coins">
 <div [ngClass]="coinStyle(coin.coinStatus)" (click)="coinDetails(coin, index) || coin.coinStatus=!coin.coinStatus">
 </div>
</div>
```

On the component, something like this:

```
coinStyle(status): string {
   if (status) {
     return 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize';
   } else {
     return 'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize';
   }
}
```

And delete the DOM manipulation on your coinDetails function.

```
 this.col = document.getElementsByClassName("resize")[index];
 this.col.className = "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize";
 this.col = document.getElementsByClassName("resize")[index];
 this.col.className = "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 resize";
```

(those 4 lines).

P.s sorry, but since you did not share your HTML I can not give you a better guide.